# Add OptionMenu on Activity Dialog

Tags: android, dialog, optionmenu

I need to add an `Option Menu` or Icon on my Activity Dialog. The `Option Menu` didnt show. I use custom theme to make custom Activity Dialog. I used a custom title too. Here my snippet code to make it clear :

manifest.xml

```
<activity
        android:name=".ModalActivity"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Custom.AlertDialog" />
```

style.xml

```
<style name="Theme.Custom.AlertDialog" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="android:windowFrame">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">false</item>
</style>
```

ModalActivity.java

```
public class ModalActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(getWindow().FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.modal_activity);

    DisplayMetrics metrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    int screenWidth = (int) (metrics.widthPixels * 0.90);

    getWindow().setLayout(screenWidth, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(R.color.colorRedTheme);
    this.setFinishOnTouchOutside(false);
    getWindow().setFeatureInt(getWindow().FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.layout.title_dialog_editor);

    final TextView customTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title_text_dialog_editor);
    if ( customTitle != null ) {
        customTitle.setText("Modal Activity");
        customTitle.setTextSize(20f);
        customTitle.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 0);
        customTitle.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#BA0B0B"));
        customTitle.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    }
    setTitle("");
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.refresh:
            return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

The problem is the menu is not show. I search regarding my case in here but there is no solution.

### Edit

Below the picture, I need add some `Option Menu` in my title but the `Option Menu` is not show

[image]

Comment: Are you getting any errors?If yes please attach your logcat too

Comment: @Mandy8055 no, there is no error but the option menu is not show in my toolbar. I dont have any idea because my normal activity (not activity dialog) use same code and the option menu is show

Comment: In that case please will you attach the screenshot of the app where the `optionsMenu` need to be shown!!!It will help me to help you with...

Comment: Ok wait, i will edit my question

Comment: I checked your code and everything seems fine for me but just for instance please have a look at [**this**](http://www.truiton.com/2015/04/android-action-bar-dialog-using-toolbar/). I'm sure this might provide you necessary help and do tell if it served your purpose.

Comment: @Mandy8055 I was thinking about add a`Toolbar` before. Oke the `Option Menu` show now with `Toolbar`, same like your reference. You can make that as answer so I can checkmark that. Thanks

Comment: @Mandy8055 haha you're welcome, Answered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you to use `Toolbar` to serve your purpose. Here is something that might help you

Add below lines in your **Layout.xml**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:elevation="8dp"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>
```

And this to your **styles.xml**

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style  name="Theme.Custom.AlertDialog" parent="Theme.AppCompat"">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <!--   your app branding color for the app bar -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">#3F51B5</item>
    <!--   darker variant for the status bar and contextual app bars -->
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#303F9F</item>
    <!--   theme UI controls like checkboxes and text fields -->
    <item name="colorAccent">#FF4081</item>
    <item name="android:windowFrame">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">false</item>

</style>

</resources>
```

And finally in your **ModalActivity.java** add below lines in your `onCreate()` method:

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

You can also refer [**this_blog**](http://www.truiton.com/2015/04/android-action-bar-dialog-using-toolbar/) for more help and support.

Regards :)